# IPv6 radvd with vlans

Tags: ipv6, radvd, icmpv6

Is it possible to configure the radvd config so that the router advertisement 
packets got a VLAN- tag? Theres a switch between my Router (software router, Ubuntu OS) and I 
 only want some VLANs to recieve router advertisements. My switch isn't that powerful to 
 filter icmpv6 type 134 packets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to configure the VLANs on the Ubuntu box. This is documented in the [VLAN page of the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan#Making_it_permanent). First you have to make sure that the VLAN module is loaded into the kernel:

```
echo "8021q" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

And then you create interfaces for the VLANs. In this example an interface is created for VLAN `10z on` eth1`and it gets IPv6 address`2001:db8:ab:cd::1/64`:

```
auto eth1.10
iface eth1.10 inet6 static
    address 2001:db8:ab:cd::1
    netmask 64
    vlan-raw-device eth1
```

After you create this interface you can configure `radvd` as usual. Here is an example based on the [IPv6 page of the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IPv6#Configure_your_Ubuntu_box_as_a_IPv6_router):

```
interface eth1.10
{
   AdvSendAdvert on;
   prefix 2001:db8:ab:cd::/64
   {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
   };
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! That was excactly what I was searching for.